# Tortiose SVN - Missing the setting to - Use "_svn" instead of ".svn"

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, icons

I just updated from SVN 1.6 to SVN 1.7.  My Icon overlays aren't showing up.  In looking at SVN's settings in 1.7, I no longer have the option to use "_svn" directories.  This is likely why I'm having issues.  Does anyone know how to make SVN 1.7 use _svn directories again?

Comment: why aren't you using default .svn directories?

Comment: As far as I know it's for compatibility with Visual Studio or Microsoft's OS's.  Either way, it's a standard that we've adopted at my company and I need to get it back if I can.

Comment: I've used the SVN on Win XP, Win Server 2003, Win 7 and Win Server 2008 R2 with Visual Studio 2010 and never had problems with .svn folders.

Comment: @christian.p the problem is because its not a valid folder name in windows. try to create a ".svn" folder for yourself.

Comment: There is no problem with .svn folder names in Windows (in general, at least)

Comment: @christian.p, do you have Silver Light App's as well?  Do you know if the .SVN is an issue with Silver Light Apps?

Comment: Related question: [Using '_svn' directories instead of '.svn' in a working copy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676916/using-svn-directories-instead-of-svn-in-a-working-copy)

Comment: @RobK. the link that crashmstr provided explains it all - VS2005 fixed the problems with .svn folders.

Comment: @dowhilefor go to cmd and type mkdir .svn to check ;)

Answer (score 6):

This is what i found in the help of the new Version.

> As of version 1.4.0 and later, the TortoiseSVN installer doesn't
>   provide the user  with the option to set the SVN_ASP_DOT_NET_HACK
>   environment variable anymore, since that caused many problems and
>   confusion for users who always install everything no matter whether
>   they know what it is for.
>
> But that option is only hidden for the user. You still can force the
>   TortoiseSVN installer to set that environment variable by setting the
>   ASPDOTNETHACK property to TRUE. For example, you can start the
>   installer like this:
>
> msiexec /i TortoiseSVN-1.4.0.msi ASPDOTNETHACK=TRUE

Answer (score 1):

With this update to TortoiseSVN, you need to manually update your working copies before you can use it (and no icon overlays will show until you update!).

Not sure about _svn

[TortoiseSVN Release Notes](http://tortoisesvn.net/tsvn_1.7_releasenotes.html)

*Update*:
I did find [Setting the SVN_ASP_DOT_NET_HACK environment variable](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-admins-aspdotnethack.html)
Which may do what you are looking for.

Comment: Do you see in your 1.7 version the setting to use the _svn folders instead of the .svn folders?

Comment: No, I'm not seeing a setting for that currently. See my updated answer. That may be what you are looking for (but also that it was only needed for VS.Net 2002)

Comment: That's actually what I'm looking for, specifically the note on VS.Net 2002.  I guess I'll just dump all of what I have right now and re-check out my code.  Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

These webservice issues have been gone since VS2005.  Only those of us stuck on .net 1.1 have no choice but to deal with the underscore hack.  I can confirm that 1.7 does indeed recognize the underscore hack, at least as far as upgrading 1.6 which was already using the hack.  msiexec /i TortoiseSVN-[1.7].msi ASPDOTNETHACK=TRUE upgrades 1.6 and does not remove the hack.  You will still have to upgrade your working copy but it works fine after that.  Again,  I can only confirm that the upgrade works,  I can't confirm if it will work from a new install but I suspect that it would.  Thank you TortoiseSVN for not leaving the hopelessly outdated out in the cold.

Answer (score 1):

Open a command prompt in your working copy folder.
Run the following commands:

```
attrib -h _svn
rename _svn .svn
attrib +h .svn
```

You can do this in all your working copies.  This worked for me after moving the working copy between computers, one where ASPDOTNETHACK was on and the other where it was off.  According to the TortoiseSVN docs, ASPDOTNETHACK is only needed for VS.NET2002.  Later versions don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to see this:

[Configuring VisualSVN Server to use _svn instead of .svn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12107/configuring-visualsvn-server-to-use-svn-instead-of-svn)

and this

http://john-sheehan.com/blog/bulk-renaming-svn-folders/

and this

http://www.giannistsakiris.com/index.php/2007/11/08/mass-rename-_svn-directories-to-svn-and-vice-versa/

Comment: Thanks Tim.  Do you know if the settings been removed in 1.7 all together?

Comment: No idea - but if the reason for them is gone then why not just move back to the standard.  Who cares what is on your local machine?  As long as SVN works it should not make a difference.

Comment: arg, because I'm stubborn.  that's about it.  I need to know for sure whether or not the WebApp issues using the .svn folder are gone now.  Especially with Silver Light Apps.  Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

I recently upgraded myself and had the same issue. I proceeding to remove what I deemed surplus to requirements overlay icons items from the registry, however this did not help. Seeing crashmstr answer I had a look and noticed the option "Upgrade SVN working copy" and that did the trick.

Right click on folder and select "Upgrade SVN working copy"