# Changing TortoiseSVN from underscore "_svn" to period ".svn" folders

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, windows-xp

I am having a problem switching a TortoiseSVN installation from using "_svn" folders to ".svn" folders.  The TortoiseSVN version is 1.7.13 and the machine is running 32 bit Windows XP.  It seems that no amount of uninstalling, restarting, and reinstalling of TortoiseSVN will force it to change from using the "_svn" folders.  I've deleted every bit of TSVN and Subversion related registry data that I could find after uninstalling the software, in addition to removing every settings related files and folders that I could find.  Any suggestions?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798027/tortiose-svn-missing-the-setting-to-use-svn-instead-of-svn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If just renaming _svn folders in existing Working Copies does not help you, you have to remove environment variable `SVN_ASP_DOT_NET_HACK` also